# adding string keys to inner arrays

Tags: php, array-walk

I wish to add string keys to my inner PHP arrays. So, I want to convert this:

```
array (size=2)
0 => array (size=3)
  0 => string 'X705' (length=4)
  1 => string 'X723' (length=4)
  2 => string 'Sue' (length=0)
1 => array (size=3)
  0 => string 'X714' (length=4)
  1 => string 'X721' (length=4)
  2 => string 'John' (length=0)
```

to this:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=3)
  'code1' => string 'X705' (length=4)
  'code2' => string 'X723' (length=4)
  'name' => string 'Sue' (length=0)
1 => 
array (size=3)
  'code1' => string 'X714' (length=4)
  'code2' => string 'X721' (length=4)
  'name' => string 'John' (length=0)
```

I think I need to use array_walk but cannot fathom it out. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to modify the original array, or create a new array with the string keys?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: You need an example of what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php) for that purpose:

```
$newarray = array_map(function($x) {
    return array("code1" => $x[0], "code2" => $x[1], "name" => $x[2]);
}, $array);
```

where `$array` is your input array.

Comment: Just what I needed. Simple and elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$item) {
  $item['code1']=$item[0];
  unset($item[0]);
  $item['code2']=$item[1];
  unset($item[1]);
  $item['name']=$item[2];
  unset($item[2]);
  $array[$key]=$item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `array_map()` but here's an alternate:

```
foreach($array as &$v) {
    $v = array_combine(array('code1','code2','name'), $v);
}
```